# grunt.js claims NaN where browser doesn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, qunit

I'm setting up grunt.js to run qunit tests and for certain tests grunt fails. The failing tests (3 out of 4 tests fail) are all where I'm adding an integer with a string implicitly causing a string concatenation. This works fine if I run the tests manually in a browser, in browser console and in the webpage that uses the code.

***What's happening here and how should I tackle it?***

**grunt output**

```
Running "qunit:all" (qunit) task
Testing html_client/tests.html F..........
>> CommonTests - Test getDateAsString
>> Message: null
>> Actual: "NaN-NaN-NaN"
>> Expected: "1980-02-13"
>> at file:...

>> CommonTests - Test getDateAsString
>> Message: null
>> Actual: "NaN-NaN-NaN"
>> Expected: "1980-12-03"
>> at file:...

>> CommonTests - Test getDateAsString
>> Message: null
>> Actual: "NaN-NaN-NaN"
>> Expected: "1980-02-03"
>> at file:...
```

**test code**

```
    QUnit.test("Test getDateAsString", function() {
        QUnit.equal( Common.getDateAsString(new Date('1980-2-13')), '1980-02-13' );
        QUnit.equal( Common.getDateAsString(new Date('1980-12-3')), '1980-12-03' );
        QUnit.equal( Common.getDateAsString(new Date('1980-12-13')), '1980-12-13' );
        QUnit.equal( Common.getDateAsString(new Date('1980-2-3')), '1980-02-03' );
    });
```

**code**

```
    var getDateAsString = function(date) {
        var dd = date.getDate();
        var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; // January is 0!
        var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

        return yyyy + '-' + ((mm < 10) ? '0' + mm : mm) + '-' + ((dd < 10) ? '0' + dd : dd);
    };
```

**SOLVED**

Rewriting the tests as such solved the problem.

```
    QUnit.test("Test getDateAsString", function() {
        QUnit.equal( Common.getDateAsString(new Date(1980, 1, 13)), '1980-02-13' );
        QUnit.equal( Common.getDateAsString(new Date(1980, 11, 3)), '1980-12-03' );
        QUnit.equal( Common.getDateAsString(new Date(1980, 11, 13)), '1980-12-13' );
        QUnit.equal( Common.getDateAsString(new Date(1980, 1, 3)), '1980-02-03' );
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new Date('1980-2-23')` syntax is not supported in every browser. You should use a library if you want consistent results in every browser, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

IE8:

```
>> new Date('1980-2-23').getDate() 
NaN 

>> new Date('1980-02-03').getDate() 
3
```

Comment: You're correct, but I only aim to support the latest ones (Mobile browsers). It also doesn't explain why only three out of four test cases fail, all four should fail with your explanation. Right?

Comment: @MdaG Syntax with proper padding works, e.g. `new Date('1980-12-13')` should be the one that passes

Comment: @MdaG here the syntax has to be precisely `yyyy-mm-dd`, double digits for both month and day. Also latest mobile browsers don't compare with latest desktop browsers. They lack features you will find on desktop ones.

Comment: Ok, thanks, then this error is localized to my tests. The real code doesn't create dates in the same way. I just wanted to make sure the date syntax comes out padded.